# Постепенный вывод информации

Tags: python, list, for

У меня есть `list()` в котором неизвестное кол-во строк информации (для примера возьмем 33)
Как сделать так чтобы оно постепенно выводила по 5 строк после команды 'Продолжить'
И когда число выведенных строк равен 30 последние и после нажатия на "Продолжить " 3 чтобы тоже выдавал

```
chek = 0
for i in msg:
    if chek == 5:
        a = input()
        if a == 'Продолжить':
            chek = 0
            continue
        else:
            break
    chek += 1
    print(i)
```

тут у меня куда-то теряется строка между обрывами 5 7,11 13

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: @yspesny исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сразу побить массив на куски и работать с ними. Если вам надо выводить каждый элемент в отдельную строку, измените вывод `print(*i, sep="\n")`

```
chunk = 5

for i in [msg[j:j+chunk] for j in range(0, len(msg), chunk)]:
    print(*i)
    a = input()
    if a != 'Продолжить':
        break
```

Comment: а как можно вот эти 5 строк перевести в str и чтоб они через /n выходили ?

Comment: в одну строку? `'/n'.join(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так решить:

```
a = [i for i in range(33)]

for index, ele in enumerate(a):
    if index % 5 == 0 and index != 0:
        text = input("Введите команду: ")
        if text != "Продолжить":
            break
        continue
    print(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с `while`

```
msg = ['что-то'] * 33
pos, part = 0, 5
while True:
    print(msg[pos:pos + part])
    pos += part
    if pos >= len(msg) or input('?: ') != 'Продолжить':
        break
```